# get_query_var not returning the value(wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url

So im using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to filter categories on my blog page, when you click on a blog I still have my menu of categories at the top of the single blog post so people can click on a category and it will take them back to the blog page but on the category selected. So on the single blog page ive added an add_query_arg to the link to return a custom url.

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'cat', $category->name, '/blog' );?>">
```

this gives me the url on my blog page as mysite.com/blog/?cat=information

then on my blog page i call the query like this

```
<?php $cat = get_query_var('cat');?>
```

Then in my javascript for filtering the categories with isotope i have

```
filter: "<?php echo $cat;?>"
```

but this is not returning anything in my javascript when i view source is just

```
filter: ""
```

i have also added this to my functions.php

```
 function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
   $vars[] = "cat";
   return $vars;
 }

//Add custom query vars
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

anyone got an idea where im going wrong?

Comment: with this line: `filter: "<?php echo $cat;?>"` are you saying your telling javascript to execute php? Or are you using that code within php to output javascript in the page content?

Comment: that bit of php is in the javascript i just want it to echo out the category name there then the javascript will filter the page to just show a certain category

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was meaning: are you outputting the javascript from inside the php so it's an inline script - in which case it CAN execute php. Or are you referencing the javascript by location like so: `<script src="/js/myscript.js">` - in which case it CANNOT execute the php. Knowing this will ensure efforts to help you take the right direction when helping diagnose the fault.

Comment: oh right, yeah the javasript is in the php file not external

Comment: Got ya :) I'm not too familiar with `add_query_arg` so can't be certain but my first thoughts are that this might be due to the $cat variable not being in the same namespace as where your trying to echo it. If you were to  `<?php echo $cat; ?>` directly after `<?php $cat = get_query_var('cat');?>` would `$cat` contain the value?

Comment: still makes it empty, i think its something to do with wordpress not allowing Custom Query String Parameters without doing what i did in the function file but its still not working even though ive added what wordpress tells you to

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I'll have to bow out and let someone more knowledgeable about `add_query_arg();`step in to help. I don't know enough about the function to be helpful. The only help I could offer will be more diagnostic than solution providing and I don't think SO is the place for doing that. It's probably worth asking this specific question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com where you might be able to find someone that's integrated Isotope in a similar way you want to.